# How to create a "Layer Blur" effect figma on circle shaped container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, effect

How to replicate Figma layer blur effect on a container with a circle shaped in Flutter?

I have a design in Figma that has a layer blur effect applied on a circle. Please refer to the image below for more details.
[image: [image]]

I tried using the Blur widget from the [blur](https://pub.dev/packages/blur) package in Flutter, but it doesn't create the same effect as in Figma. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Blur(
            blur: 10,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(180),
            blurColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 14, 81),
            child: Container(
              width: 302,
              height: 302,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the result of my code:
[image]

Comment: you want some thing like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/THNgy.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U don't need to use Blur package if u have the color *(Blur package works better as img background ). What u r trying to achieve can be done in 2 ways

```dart
1: Container(
      height:80,
      width:80,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        shape:BoxShape.circle,
        boxShadow:  [
          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 30, spreadRadius: 2, color: Colors.red)
        ],
      ),
    )
2. Container(
      height:80,
      width:80,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        shape:BoxShape.circle,
        gradient: const RadialGradient(colors: [
             Colors.red,
             Colors.red.withOpacity(.5),
             Colors.red.withOpacity(.1),
         ]),
      ),
    )
```